# Equals condition in aws cloudFormation YAML giving error

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have an app in two regions, and I wanted to add an eventbridge rule for just `ap-southeast-2` region,
The rule is working but after adding this condition to the rule, it give me error.

```
EventRule:
    Condition: IsSydneyRegion
    ...RULE PARAMS
```

I wanted to check if the region is in `ap-southeast-2` with

```
  IsSydneyRegion: !Equals 
    - !Ref AWS::Region
    - "ap-southeast-2"
```

I have also tried with

```
IsSydneyRegion: !Equals ["ap-southeast-2", !Ref AWS::Region]
```

But in Cloudformation is giving me this error
`Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies`

Comment: I don't think that's where the error is coming from. Show us the whole template

Answer (score 0):

@Paolo is probably correct. What you are showing us should not produce that error.

Your error looks to be coming from the fact that you are referencing the newly conditioned eventrule by another resource without also conditioning that resource. This will leads to unresolved dependency if eventrule is not being created (condition is false).